# How do I maximize the objective $0 x_1 + 0 x_2 + \dots + 0 x_n$ in linear programming?

Tags: linear-programming, simplex

Given this problem for instance:

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{maximize} & 0 x_1 + 0 x_2 + 0 x_3\\ \text{subject to} & x_1 + 3x_2 + 2x_3 = 3\\ & 2x_1 + 7x_2 + x_3 = 4\\ & 3x_1 + x_2 + 2x_3 = 5\\ & x_1, x_2, x_3 \geq 0\end{array}$$

I know how to use Simplex in general using tableau method
to solve standard linear programming problems. How would I set up my initial tableau here, if my objective function is zero?

Comment: If you are saying the objective function is identically zero, then the only issue is whether the constraints are feasible or not.  Please have a look at the [introduction to posting mathematical notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) and make an effort to express yourself more clearly.  Equality constraints(?) are easily solved by elimination rather than by the simplex method.

Comment: Assuming the constraints are feasible. I understand this could be solve by standard elimination, but I am working with very large numbers with many rows and columns (and is underdetermined), and I must find a nonnegative solution. Simplex has been suggested by other forums, and they say to maximize objective function with 0x1 +..+0xn. I just dont know how to set up this up

Comment: If you are just asking about how to plug into a numerical algorithm that would ordinarily use an input vector $[f_1, f_2, ..., f_n]$ to maximize $\sum_{i=1}^n f_i x_i$, just use input vector $[0, 0, ..., 0]$.

Comment: Nevertheless that is the problem to be solved, and focusing on the identically zero objective function is irrelevant.  Many Readers will be unsure (because of the lack of MathJax formatting) whether you have equality constraints (the use of subscripts will make your constraints more readable).

Comment: If the math formatting seems daunting, I will try my hand at editing the post (subject to your correcting or rolling back my changes).

Comment: If you don't have time to learn the MathJax syntax, you may try the [online WYSIWYG equation editor](http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php).  In any case, there's no excuse for not typesetting math in MathJax on Math.SE.

Comment: This boils down to finding the reduced row-echelon form of the augmented matrix
$$
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c} 
1&3&2&3\\
2&7&1&4\\
3&1&2&5
\end{array}\right]
$$
which is
$$
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c} 
1&0&0&8/7\\
0&1&0&1/7\\
0&0&1&5/7
\end{array}\right].
$$

Comment: If you insist on using the simplex method, use at the 2-phase method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [CVXPY](http://www.cvxpy.org) to solve the linear program:

```
>>> from cvxpy import *
>>> x1 = Variable()
>>> x2 = Variable()
>>> x3 = Variable()
>>> objective = Maximize(0)
>>> constraints = [  x1 + 3*x2 + 2*x3 == 3, 
                   2*x1 + 7*x2 +   x3 == 4,
                   3*x1 +   x2 + 2*x3 == 5, 
                   x1 >= 0, x2 >= 0, x3 >= 0]
>>> prob = Problem(objective, constraints)
>>> prob.solve()
-0.0
>>> prob.status
'optimal'
```

A feasible solution is

```
>>> x1.value
1.142857142857143
>>> x2.value
0.14285714285714277
>>> x3.value
0.7142857142857143
```

---

Using [SymPy](http://www.sympy.org) to perform Gaussian elimination on the augmented matrix:

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> M = Matrix([[1,3,2,3],
                [2,7,1,4],
                [3,1,2,5]])
>>> M.rref()
(Matrix([
[1, 0, 0, 8/7],
[0, 1, 0, 1/7],
[0, 0, 1, 5/7]]), [0, 1, 2])
```

which is a nonnegative $3$-vector and, thus, admissible. Note that this solution is unique.